# Why newly released package version is not available in Partner Security Portal scanner?

Tags: security, security-review, partner-portal, security-scanner, source-scanner

We have released a new minor 2GMP release version and try to check it for Security and Quality rules in [`Partner Security Portal` scanner](https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/PackageScannerMain), but the new version doesn't show up in the picklist for `Select Package Version ID to scan:`.

We have create a new beta version for the future release and this version is shown in the picklist, but the released version and the previous beta version is not shown.

Why is this not shown?

The latest available package version build number is 32, while the released version build number is 34.

I can't find anything in [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_partner_security_portal_scanners.htm) or [here](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scannerhelp) to explain this.

Comment: By "minor release version" I assume you don't mean patch version a.b.c but rather a release version a.b, right? One observation from our perspective - you only see the 10 "most recent" versions, including all betas and any deprecated versions (release or beta), usually in version order. This means if you have 10 or more betas for your *next* release, you cannot select the current release. We reported this to Salesforce and had to have help from the Security Review team to "manually" scan our code for our current release (this was 1GP it must be said).

Comment: If I meant patch version, I would have mentioned that. I know about limitation of 10 most recent version, we have versions 1.13.0.32 and 1.14.0.1 available for scan, but versions 1.13.0.33 and 1.33.0.34 not available for scan. We don't use patch versions

Comment: I only asked to make sure I understood.

Answer (score 0):

My client has opened a case in Salesforce support.

Meanwhile I have some conjectures.

There were no changes between the beta version 33 and released version 34 and there were only LWC changes between version 32 and version 33.

Since Checkmarx scanner verifies only Apex, this might be the reason for the package version not showing up in the checkmarx scanner, since there were no Apex changes between versions 32 through 34.

Still need to confirm this conjecture with Salesforce Support.